# How do I configure Outlook 2011 (mac) to display contact pictures when you read email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2011

On Outlook 2008 and 2010 (Windows) I appreciated the show contact picture on emails but I was not able to find the same feature on Outlook 2011 on OS X.

Clicking on contact name to see the picture is not a solution, I am looking for a solution that would not require me to do an additional click.